# sum data in multiple CSV's based on row and column python

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have multiple csv's and I want to add data present in these two csv's based on row and column keys
Example:

```
input1.csv
account,param1,param2,param3
D1,2,-1,0
D2,3,2,-2
D4,12,-1,-2
D3,1,1,0

input2.csv
account,param1,param2,param3
D4,22,-1,0
D6,3,2,-2
D1,-2,-1,-2
D3,1,1,0

output.csv
account,param1,param2,param3
D1,0,-2,0
D2,3,2,-2
D3,2,2,0
D4,34,-2,-2
D6,3,2,-2
```

So, In output.csv I need to have all accounts present in both csv's and for common accounts the param values needs to be added.

**Note**:The accounts are not in serial order

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: @Mitch I don't have a clue to solve this. any suggestion also are welcome:(y)

Comment: then start looking at pd.concat

Comment: @Pavan If you load your CSVs into DataFrames, look at `pd.concat`, update your question accordingly and still have a problem I'd be happy to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way using `pd.concat`

```
In [824]: df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f) for f in ['input1.csv', 'input2.csv']), ignore_index=True)

In [825]: df
Out[825]:
  account  param1  param2  param3
0      D1       2      -1       0
1      D2       3       2      -2
2      D4      12      -1      -2
3      D3       1       1       0
4      D4      22      -1       0
5      D6       3       2      -2
6      D1      -2      -1      -2
7      D3       1       1       0

In [826]: df.groupby('account', as_index=False).sum()
Out[826]:
  account  param1  param2  param3
0      D1       0      -2      -2
1      D2       3       2      -2
2      D3       2       2       0
3      D4      34      -2      -2
4      D6       3       2      -2

In [827]: df.groupby('account', as_index=False).sum().to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```